# Is there any way to draw on canvas, when that is zoomed?

Tags: android, android-canvas, zooming, pinchzoom, android-bitmap

Here drawing is not performed while the canvas is resized.
It just checks wheather there is a multiple touch, and returns.

Here is what I do:

```
@override
 public final boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
 if (event.getPointerCount() >= 2) {
            if (!zoomed) {
                zoomed = true;
                drawing.setStarted(false);
            }

            return false;
        }

        if (zoomed && event.getPointerCount() < 2) {
            Log.d("Zoomed", "Drawing");

        }

        if (zoomed) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                zoomed = false;
            }
            return false;

        }


            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
....
    // here I handle the corresponding event

invalidate();
return true;
}
```

The question is the following:

How can I draw on canvas, while that is zoomed?

Thanks much in advance!!!

Comment: I call invalidate() after I handle the corresponding action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invalidate reschedule the redesign event.

```
   if (zoomed && event.getPointerCount() < 2) {
        Log.d("Zoomed", "Drawing");
    }

    if (zoomed) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            zoomed = false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you much !!! Actually, in this case the canvas is resized only when I hold 2 fingers on the screen. Is it possible to add drawing to canvas, while that is zoomed? Thanks much in advance!!!

Comment: the drawing event is not aware of your zooming. If you call invalidate the redraw will be scheduled again. If it is not redrawing can mean just two things, 1. you are not calling invalidate(), 2. there is nothing new to be redrawn

Answer (score 1):

if I understand it right, when you have two fingers on the screen you call

```
return false;
```

If you want to trigger drawing, you should call

```
invalidate();
```

before that return statement, right?

Comment: Thank you !!!!I resize the canvas. That canvas remains resized. Now I want to add drawing to the canvas in that resized mode. However, according to my code, when I touch the screen, the canvas returns to its prior state, thus I am not able to draw on the resized screen. Thanks much for any idea.

Comment: can you update the code in your original question so that we see the current version?